# Why do I only get first element in Javascript array passed from Silverlight?

Tags: javascript, silverlight, arrays

I'm attempting to pass out an array of strings from a Silverlight application to a Javascript function.  However I only seem to get the first element of the array, rather than the whole array.  I've reproduced it with the simple code below:

Silverlight:

```
 string[] Names = new string[5];
 Names[0] = "Test1";
 Names[1] = "Test2";
 Names[2] = "Test3";
 Names[3] = "Test4";
 Names[4] = "Test5";

 HtmlPage.Window.Invoke("PopulateNames", Names);
```

Javascript:

```
function PopulateNames(names)
{
    window.alert(names);
}
```

In this case I only ever see "Test1" with the above code, or "undefined" if I replace window.alert(names) with window.alert(names[0]).

Does anyone know how I should be doing this to get all the elements out to the Javascript function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`Invoke` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.browser.scriptobject.invoke%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) takes an array of parameters.
Therefore, your five strings are being passed as five string parameters to the function.

You need to pass a nested array, like this:

```
HtmlPage.Window.Invoke("PopulateNames", new object[] { Names });
```

Answer (score 2):

There is another property of a javascript function object. Its arguments. You can access the complete object array you pass through this arguments object. Try debugging your script and you will understand what I say. If you access the argument array of the function like '`funcation(myargs[])`', the myargs will refer to the first value in the passed in array.